# Getting background-color of body in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an html page with iframe in it. There is a website in the iframe. The domains of the website and the web page are the same. I want to get background-color of the website in the frame from the web page. How can I do that?

For example, I want to get the background color of the website in iframe from the html page below.

```html
<html>

  <head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <iframe id="my-iframe" frameBorder="0"
      src="https://MYWEBSİTE.COM (Same domain)" title="My Website">
    </iframe>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with JavaScript using `.getComputedStyle()` of the iframe's body by selecting `.contentWindow.document.body` then selecting the body's background color.

```
var iFrameEl = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
var backgroundColor = iFrameEl.contentWindow.getComputedStyle(iFrameEl.contentWindow.document.body).backgroundColor;
```

Comment: I ran these codes in console, but it return "undefined".

Comment: I made a mistake. You need to get the style of the body by using `.getComputedStyle()`. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Please upvote if the answer was useful. Thanks